Does Wix toolset 5 support regex validation?
I am using Wix toolset 5 to build an .msi installer for a .NET8 windows service.
Users are able to set certain configuration settings through a Custom Dialog and to validate the inputs I used (by passing the Custom actions burden) DisableCondition and EnableCondition on the 'Next' PushButton :
Control Id="Next" 
Type="PushButton" 
X="236" 
Y="243" 
Width="56" 
Height="17" 
Default="yes" 
Text="!(loc.CustomNext)" 
DisableCondition="PROVIDER_CHOICE &lt;&gt; &quot;!(loc.Provider1)&quot; AND
PROVIDER_CHOICE &lt;&gt; &quot;!(loc.Provider2)&quot;" 
EnableCondition="PROVIDER_CHOICE &lt;&gt; &quot;!(loc.Provider1)&quot; OR
PROVIDER_CHOICE &lt;&gt; &quot;!(loc.Provider2)&quot;">  

This simple checking enables or disables the 'Next' button if the user does not pick any of the available values of a ComboBox on the same Custom Dialog :
<Control Id="OptionComboBox" Type="ComboBox" X="20" Y="116" Width="150"
Height="20" Property="PROVIDER_CHOICE">
<ComboBox Property="PROVIDER_CHOICE">
<ListItem Value="!(loc.Provider1)" Text="!(loc.Provider1)" />
<ListItem Value="!(loc.Provider2)" Text="!(loc.Provider2)" />
</ComboBox>
</Control>

This works just fine, however I now need to add a regex validation of a new Edit control. In short does anyone know if Wix5 toolset supports regex validation on Edit controls (without the use of Custom Actions)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated ...
I tried adding a regex condition to the expressions :
<Control Id="Next"
Type="PushButton" 
X="236" 
Y="243" 
Width="56" 
Height="17" 
Default="yes" 
Text="!(loc.CustomNext)" 
DisableCondition="PROVIDER_CHOICE &lt;&gt; &quot;!(loc.ImpactProvider)&quot; AND
PROVIDER_CHOICE &lt;&gt; &quot;!(loc.SoftoneProvider)&quot; OR NOT (APIKEY_INPUT
AND STRLEN(APIKEY_INPUT) = 36 AND APIKEY_INPUT &lt;&gt; &quot;[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*
[^-]*-[^-]*&quot;)"
EnableCondition="PROVIDER_CHOICE = &quot;!(loc.ImpactProvider)&quot; OR
PROVIDER_CHOICE = &quot;!(loc.SoftoneProvider)&quot; AND (APIKEY_INPUT AND
STRLEN(APIKEY_INPUT) = 36 AND APIKEY_INPUT &lt;&gt; &quot;[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*
[^-]*&quot;)">
<Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="1" />
</Control>

